# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab.graphics.barcode.code93' in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, barcode, reportlab

I  am converting a python file to .exe using pyinstaller v5.0.1, but I got this error when I run the exe file:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab.graphics.barcode.code93'
```

Note that the python file is working perfectly and I'm not even using code93 in my code.

Comment: Does your script use reportlab?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by adding an import for all this libs even if I don't use them:

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code93
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import usps
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import usps4s
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import ecc200datamatrix
```

Comment: It seems odd that you would need this, but glad you got it working.